# How can I make Xcode not auto indent Eureka forms code in a weird way?

Tags: xcode, auto-indent, eureka-forms

When I use Eureka forms, Xcode seems to like to format it in a way that could cause confusion.

I'll use the one of the code blocks in the README as an example:

```
let row  = SwitchRow("SwitchRow") { row in      // initializer
    row.title = "The title"
    }.onChange { row in
        row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "The title expands when on" : "The title"
        row.updateCell()
    }.cellSetup { cell, row in
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
        cell.textLabel?.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
}
```

This really makes my OCD go off. The last `}` isn't inline with all the other ones feels so annoying.

I would like to format it like so:

```
let row  = SwitchRow("SwitchRow") { row in      // initializer
    row.title = "The title"
    }.onChange { row in
        row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "The title expands when on" : "The title"
        row.updateCell()
    }.cellSetup { cell, row in
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
        cell.textLabel?.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
    }
```

Or this:

```
let row  = SwitchRow("SwitchRow") { row in      // initializer
    row.title = "The title"
}.onChange { row in
    row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "The title expands when on" : "The title"
    row.updateCell()
}.cellSetup { cell, row in
    cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
}.cellUpdate { cell, row in
    cell.textLabel?.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
}
```

So I went to the preference pane of Xcode and looked for things like custom indentation. I thought there would be something similar to the formatting settings in IntelliJ, but I found nothing.

Then I found the closest thing to what I'm looking for - Automatic Indent. So I unchecked the checkbox for `}`, like the:

[image]

But as I type `.onChange {` then press enter, this happens:

```
    let row = SwitchRow("") {
        row in
        }.onChange {

    }
```

How can make it not automatically indent to that? I want one of the styles mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use the non-trailing syntax, i.e. with extra parentheses (which admittedly bloat the code a bit) the auto-indentation should work fine.

Your example code gets formatted to:

```
let row  = SwitchRow("SwitchRow", { row in      // initializer
    row.title = "The title"
}).onChange({ row in
    row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "The title expands when on" : "The title"
    row.updateCell()
}).cellSetup({ cell, row in
    cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
}).cellUpdate({ cell, row in
    cell.textLabel?.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this does not prevent Xcode from formatting it *every time*, I think this suffices in most cases.

The solution is to uncheck auto indentation for `{`:

[image]

Apparently what those checkboxes control is "whether to auto indent when these keys are pressed".

If the `{` box is checked, Xcode will auto indent the current line when I type `{`, moving the whole `}.onChange{` line to the right. If it is unchecked, this will not happen.